# Как узнать размеры экрана пользователя в мм? JavaScript или PHP

Tags: php, javascript, android, frontend, экран

Количество пикселей узнать могу без проблем. А вот диагональ в дюймах или кол-во пикселей на дюйм? Подскажите функции для этого дела?

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать элемент, которому через css задать размер в дюймах (width:1in), а затем в JS взять размер в пикселях через element.offsetWidth;

Собственно, получится количество пикселей на дюйм. Других вариантов лично я не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

На 100% узнать не получится никак. 
Плотность точек конкретной матрицы очень индивидуальна.
 Но приблизительно можно реализовать, как предложили выше:

```
<div id="hidden_ruler" style="width:10in; visibility: hidden;">&nbsp;</div>
<script>
    var hidden_ruler = document.getElementById('hidden_ruler');
    var length_in_pixels = hidden_ruler.clientWidth;
    var density = Number(10 / length_in_pixels);
    var width_in_inches = Number(window.screen.width * density);
    var height_in_inches = Number(window.screen.height * density);
    var diagonal_in_inches = (Math.sqrt( ( Math.pow(width_in_inches,2) + Math.pow(height_in_inches,2) ) )).toFixed(1);

    document.write(diagonal_in_inches + '"');
</script>
```

У меня отклонение от реального размера составило 3% ))

https://jsfiddle.net/15mx0ke6/13/